# I have designed a rate limiter in java. I want to simulate two users one with credit limit and one without credit limit

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my complete implementation of Rate limiter.
I want to simulate two users, one with credit limit and without any credit limit, such that the user having credit limit allows more requests to go through. I want to highlight that difference through my rate limiter example. However, no matter I apply credit limit or not, I am getting the same number of requests for both type of users.

As of now I am running a loop for 10 seconds, and the number of requests allowed per window (that is per second) is 50, so in total 500 requests are going through.
How can I modify my driver code to show that if credit limit is turned off for a user, it will allow lesser number of requests.

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        UserBucketCreator userBucketCreator1 = new UserBucketCreator(1, false);

        int totalTime = 10 * 1000;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int numberOfConsumed = 0;
        int totalRequests = 0;
        while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < totalTime) {
            totalRequests++;
            boolean consumeSuccess = userBucketCreator1.accessApplication();
            if (consumeSuccess) {
                numberOfConsumed++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("total no of requests made = " + totalRequests);
        System.out.println("no of consumed request = " + numberOfConsumed);
        System.out.println("time taken = " + totalTime);
        System.out.println("no of request per window expected = " + TokenBucketConstants.numberOfRequest);


    }
}



public class TokenBucket {
    private int numberOfTokenAvailable;
    private int numberOfRequests;
    private int windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliSeconds;
    private long lastRefillTime;
    private long nextRefillTime;
    private int maxBucketSize;
    private boolean applyCreditRequests;

    public TokenBucket(int maxBucketSize, int numberOfRequests, int windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliSeconds, boolean applyCreditRequests) {
        this.maxBucketSize = maxBucketSize;
        this.numberOfRequests = numberOfRequests;
        this.windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliSeconds = windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliSeconds;
        this.applyCreditRequests = applyCreditRequests;
        this.refill();
    }

    public boolean tryConsume() {
        refill();
        if (this.numberOfTokenAvailable > 0) {
            this.numberOfTokenAvailable--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void refill() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() < this.nextRefillTime) {
            return;
        }
        this.lastRefillTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.nextRefillTime = this.lastRefillTime + this.windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliSeconds;
        if (applyCreditRequests) {
            int creditRequest = this.numberOfTokenAvailable + this.numberOfRequests;
            this.numberOfTokenAvailable = Math.min(this.maxBucketSize, creditRequest);
        } else {
            this.numberOfTokenAvailable = this.numberOfRequests;
        }
    }
}



public class TokenBucketConstants {
    public static int numberOfRequest = 50;

    public static int windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliSeconds = 1 * 1000;

    public static int maxBucketSize = 100;
}


@Getter
@Setter
public class UserBucketCreator {
    private int userId;
    int maxCredits;
    Map<Integer, TokenBucket> bucket;

    public UserBucketCreator(int id, boolean applyCreditRequests) {
        this.bucket = new HashMap<>();
        this.userId = id;
        bucket.put(id, new TokenBucket(TokenBucketConstants.maxBucketSize,
                TokenBucketConstants.numberOfRequest,
                TokenBucketConstants.windowSizeForRateLimitInMilliSeconds, applyCreditRequests));
    }

    boolean accessApplication() {
        return bucket.get(userId).tryConsume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver code is hitting our API at a very fast rate, so our API is consuming all the tokens and credits are not getting accumulated at all.

Modified the driver code by removing the loop which runs for 10 secs with the below code-

Driver code-

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        UserBucketCreator userWithCredit = new UserBucketCreator(1, true);
        UserBucketCreator userWithoutCredit = new UserBucketCreator(2, false);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            simulateUserActivity(userWithoutCredit, "User without credit:");
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            simulateUserActivity(userWithCredit, "User with credit:");
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    private static void simulateUserActivity(UserBucketCreator user, String userType) {
        int consumedRequests = 0;
        int totalRequests = 0;

        user.accessApplication();
        consumedRequests++;
        totalRequests++;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            if (user.accessApplication()) {
                consumedRequests++;
            }
            totalRequests++;
        }

        System.out.println(userType);
        System.out.println("  Total requests made: " + totalRequests);
        System.out.println("  Consumed requests: " + consumedRequests);
    }
}
```

Output-

```
User without credit:
  Total requests made: 12
  Consumed requests: 6
User with credit:
  Total requests made: 12
  Consumed requests: 10
```

Here, I have introduced a sleep of 2 secs, which allows few tokens to go in credit. This credit will be used for subsequent requests.